# Spring 2.x multiple datasources and p6spy

Tags: java, spring-boot, datasource, p6spy

I've created a multiple datasource setup with spring-boot.
It looks like this:

application.yaml:

```yaml
app:
   db1:
      jdbc-url:...
      username:...
      password:...
   db2:...
```

Config-class:

```java
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class DataSourceConfig {

        @Bean(name = "db1")
        @Primary
        @ConfigurationProperties("app.db1")
        public DataSource statusServiceDataSource(){
                return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        }

        @Bean(name = "db2")
        @ConfigurationProperties("app.db2")
        public DataSource identifierResolverServiceDataSource(){
                return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        }
```

I use the datasource this way:

```java
@Autowired
@Qualifier("db2")
DataSource db2;
```

Until here everything works fine.
Now I wanted to include p6spy depending on a value of the properties, but I get different errors.

First approach:

```java
return new P6DataSource(DataSourceBuilder.create().build());
```

leads to:

```java
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dataSource or dataSourceClassName or jdbcUrl is required.
```

Second approach:

```java
return DataSourceBuilder.create().type(P6DataSource.class).build();
```

leads to:

```java
P6DataSource: no value for Real Data Source Name, cannot perform jndi lookup
```

Looking at the P6Spy docs, I thought my approach was enough, but It looks like it isn't. What can I do to solve the problem?
Do I really have to go the whole way with defining jndi/lookUp names for my 7+ DataSources?

Also when looking up my datasource properties in application.yaml I get an error from IntelliJ saying "Cannot resolve configuration property", which is strange, as the app works just fine with all datasources without p6spy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working in a similar solution. I couldn't use the spring boot autoconfiguration so... first thing to do is to add your maven dependency for p6spy. Then, you need a `psy.properties` where you could add your driver to driverlist like this (DB2 example)

```
driverlist=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
```

I had troubles at first using P6DataSource, so I tried the url + driver approach in order to test the library configurations.

Once the url + driver approach worked for me, I returned to P6DataSource

https://p6spy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration.html

Maybe you could try it